# Use the output of one query to input another query python

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7

Following is my code,

```
connect=Tl.connection.Connection()
a= connnect.connect('dbname', schema='schemaname')
q='''select id, id1 from table1;'''
w= Tl.datatool.todf(a(q))
id=w.id
id1=w.id1
```

Now for each id and id1, I need to execute the second query, it should be like a loop and should be stored in a dataframe,

The query I am looking for is,

```
select id2 from table2 where x=id and y=id1;
```

I am trying,

```
for i in id:
    for j in id1:
        q2='''select id2 from table2 where x=%i and y=%i;''' (int(id), int(id1))
        print a(q2)
```

But I am not able to get the exact output. I am getting the following error,

```
   TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

The output I am looking for is, for all the values for id and id1, I need id2 to be fetched and all the values should be stored in a dataframe.

Can anybody help me in doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot to use the `%` operator:

```
    q2='''select id2 from table2 where x=%i and y=%i;''' (int(id), int(id1))
```

should read

```
    q2='''select id2 from table2 where x=%i and y=%i;''' %(int(id), int(id1))
```

Answer (score 0):

That should work, but it's very very very unlike SQL. In fact, you're circumventing the features of relational databases by doing this. You should probably use a subquery; use the official MySQL documentation for more information.

Comment: I am getting the following error,

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: obviously, add that information to your original question.

Comment: I can understand that, but I have nearly 1,00,000 records and If I use a subquery totally, it is not gng to get completed. So only i am using individual queries for each id.

Comment: But your code is bound to be slower, and worse. Don't do that. Why should you do something like that? It's bad from an architectural point of view!

Comment: If I use like this, each query would take 4-5 secs and the script would complete in one hour, but if i do like that, it would take ages to complete.

Comment: no, I'm absolutely certain that if you're doing the subquery right, it should be much faster.

Comment: It there a way I can store all the results in the dataframe? storing the output of this to a dataframe?

Comment: you might need to play around with the subquery syntax, to reach your goal. maybe something like "SELECT * FROM TABLE_2 WHERE ROW(x,y)=(SELECT id,id1 from table_1)"; be cautious, I've only played with databases for like 14 days, and it's been eight years ago.

Comment: Also now that I have corrected, Since I have called a for inside a for, for each i, all the Js are executed, Can both i and j be ran parallely?

Comment: Recommending to close this question, since it's based on a simple typographical error :)

Comment: Actually I have not closed it because, I have not found a solution to loop it on parallel and also store it in a dataframe.. Can you help me in that?

Comment: No, not under this question, also your loop approach is stupid, as I told you.